# C# - call javascript function onclick and passing string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have written a line of code to call a javascript function from the code-behind.

```
String strViewQuote = "<img src='Images/Edit.png' onclick='ViewQuote(" + sdr["QuoteID"] + ", " + sdr["ContactID"] + ", " + sdr["CompanyID"] + "," + sdr["Flag"].ToString() + ")'/>";
```

However, when I click on the button on the page, I get a 'Uncaught ReferenceError: WhateverValue is not defined.

I am guessing that it is because the String value coming from sdr["Flag"].toString() is not within quotes but I am unsure how to properly add the quotes

Comment: I forgot to mention that this string gets appended to another string to build a return string for a jQuery datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try with escape (\")

```
String strViewQuote = "<img src='Images/Edit.png' onclick='ViewQuote(" + sdr["QuoteID"] + ", " + sdr["ContactID"] + ", " + sdr["CompanyID"] + ",\"" + sdr["Flag"].ToString() + "\")'/>";
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this gets appended to another string as a return string for a jquery datatable. So when I put the escape character, it fails with the datatable data load

Comment: This is the return string for the jquery database strOutput = strOutput + "[\"" + sdr["QuoteID"] + "\"," + "\"" + sdr["QuoteDateTime"].ToString() + "\"," + "\"" + sdr["FullName"].ToString() + "\"," + "\"" + sdr["Total"].ToString() + "\"," + "\"" + sdr["Status"].ToString() + "\"," + "\"" + strViewQuote + "\"],";

Comment: try double escape  (\\") then. This way double escape (\\\) will be interpreted as (\\) after first return.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the values within the pair of `'` SO the string will be like this:

```
string strViewQuote = "<img src='Images/Edit.png' 
                      onclick='ViewQuote('" + sdr["QuoteID"] + "','" + 
                      sdr["ContactID"] + "','" + sdr["CompanyID"] + "','" + 
                      sdr["Flag"].ToString() + "')'/>";
```